# How can I take different MenuItem controls and use them in one ContextMenu?

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu, menuitem

For example, I have a simple control below in xaml:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header = "Open in new tab"/>
    <MenuItem Header = "Open in new window"/>
    <MenuItem Header = "Open in incognito window"/>
    <Separator Padding="0"/>
    <MenuItem Header = "Edit..."/>
    <Separator Padding="0"/>
    <MenuItem Header = "Cut"/>
    <MenuItem Header = "Copy"/>
    <MenuItem Header = "Paste"/>
    <Separator Padding="0"/>
    <MenuItem Header = "Delete"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Which produces:

[image: ContextMenu]

I want the Cut/Copy/Paste MenuItem elements to sit in their own control. However, Wpf restricts me from just declaring 3 MenuItems in a control without a parent element. So I tried putting the MenuItems in a Menu, Grid, ItemsControl, and other controls with no luck. The formatting was weird. All i want to do is abstract the Cut/Copy/Paste into a seperate control, and have the end product look identical to the xaml above. Here were my failed attempts:

MyContextMenu.xaml:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header = "Open in new tab"/>
    <MenuItem Header = "Open in new window"/>
    <MenuItem Header = "Open in incognito window"/>
    <Separator Padding="0"/>
    <MenuItem Header = "Edit..."/>
    <Separator Padding="0"/>
    <ref:MyCutCopyPaste/>
    <Separator Padding="0"/>
    <MenuItem Header = "Delete"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

MyCutCopyPaste.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <MenuItem Header = "Cut"/>
    <MenuItem Header = "Copy"/>
    <MenuItem Header = "Paste"/>
<Grid>
```

I can probably take my solution and play around with formatting, but there has to be an easy solution that I'm oblivious too. I know I can also declare each Menu Item (Cut, Copy, and Paste) into it's own xaml file. But I'd like to keep all three in one file, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can define those MenuItems as resources and use it in the contextmenu. Refer the below code.

```
<StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>                
            <MenuItem x:Key="Cut" Header="Cut" x:Shared="false"/>
            <MenuItem x:Key="Copy" Header="Copy" x:Shared="false"/>
            <MenuItem x:Key="Paste" Header="Paste" x:Shared="false"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Button Content="Button 1">
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="Cut"/>
                    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="Copy"/>
                    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="Paste"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Open in new tab"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Button 2">
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="Cut"/>
                    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="Copy"/>
                    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="Paste"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Open in new window"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: I need the cut, copy, and paste in a separate file. So if those are in resources of a separate file, the client code can't access it.

Comment: You can add these files into a ResourceDictionary and use it.

Comment: You add these menuitems as resources in a resourcedictionary and reuse use it other places.

Comment: I understand, but for my infrastructure(mef/mvvm) setup, it'd be easier to have each menu item in it's own control. Also, I don't want to declare each menuitem individually from the client side. It'd be nice to just reference the view. I want to Still wondering if there's a way to do this without going the resources route. Thanks for the suggestion though.